# VB.Net My.Forms

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a small application, written in visual basic.

I have 4 forms in the project, however when I try to access them using the My.Forms collection only 2 are displayed to select from? I also tried manually typing the name of one of the other forms that I need to access, but I get the error that the form `is not a member of 'MyProjects.MyForms'`.

Do I need to add the other 2 forms to this collection? Shouldn't it happen automatically, as I didn't add the other 2?

Thanks

----EDIT----

I think the issue is due to me renaming the forms incorrectly. Is there a way to manually edit the My.Forms collection without having to create the forms from scratch again?

----EDIT----

The issue comes from me passing variables to the sub new method:

```
Public Sub New(id As Int32)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        MsgBox(id)

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

Am I declaring the variable wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @tony I've found the issue, it's when I add the Public Sub New to the designer code (I need to pass a variable to the form when opening it). Do you know how I can bypass the or fix it being removed from the My.Forms collection?

Comment: `when I try to access them using the My.Forms collection` You shouldn't be doing this. If you need to open form B from A, instantiate form B in A's code and open it there, giving proper ownership as argument. This will maintain proper form hierarchy and will take care of form closing order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I'm too late to help you out with your question, but for anyone else who needs help with this, I also determined that my form was removed from the My.Forms collection when I included a variable argument as part of my New() sub. I solved this problem by also including a New() sub that did not take any arguments (in other words, I overloaded the New() method). So in robbiecutting's example, the code would look like this:

```
Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Public Sub New(id As Int32)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        MsgBox(id)

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```